# SQLAlchemy one to many query output

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to get a list of `planes` and all of their corresponding `bookings`, ideally with a list of planes where each plane has a list of bookings as one of it's properties so it can be easily json encoded. How can I do this with SQLAlchemy? I suspect SQLAlchemy has some powerful features to make this easy, I'd rather not have to do 2 queries and process the results.

Eg result:

```
Plane
- id:       -- 1
- name:     -- Eagle Bravo
- bookings: -- Booking1, Booking2, Booking3

Plane
- id:       -- 2
- name:     -- Charlie Bravo
- bookings: -- Booking4, Booking5, Booking6

Plane
- id:       -- 3
- name:     -- Alpha Bravo
- bookings: -- Booking7, Booking8, Booking9
```

Plane and Booking models:

```
class Booking(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = db.relationship('Person', backref=db.backref('Bookings', lazy='dynamic'))
    plane_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plane.id'))

    def __init__(self, start_date, end_date, person_id):
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.person_id = person_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Booking... %r>'

    def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}


class Plane(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Plane... %r>'

    def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a one to many relationship in your Plane class as follows.
models.py

```
class Plane(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    bookings=db.relationship('Bookings', backref='plane', lazy='dynamic')
```

You can then get all your plane bookings by passing a planes variable to your view as follows

controller.py

```
@app.route('/list')
def plane_list():
    planes=Plane.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', planes=planes)
```

Views.py

```
{% for plane in planes %}
  {{plane.id}]
  {{plane.name}}
  {%for booking in plane.bookings.all()%}
       {{booking.id}},       

   {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Documented here: http://techarena51.com/index.php/one-to-many-relationships-with-flask-sqlalchemy/

I wrote similar code for one post to many comments: https://github.com/Leo-g/flask-blog/blob/master/app/templates/single.html
https://github.com/Leo-g/flask-blog/blob/master/app/models.py